# How do I fix my zsh prompt now that I’ve upgraded to snow leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, zsh

I recently upgraded my system to snow leopard and now my prompt doesn't work properly. I have this line in my .zshrc file:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_no_bold[cyan]%}%n@%{$fg_no_bold[red]%}%m%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}$(git_branch)%{$reset_color%}: '
```

(where "git_branch" is a function that give me information about the current git branch I'm working on). The problem is that the colors and "git_branch" function aren't being evaluated, they are taken literally, so my prompt is:

```
%{$fg_no_bold[cyan]%}username@%{$fg_no_bold[red]%}machinename%{$fg_no_bold[green]%}$(git_branch)%{$reset_color%}:
```

The colors are nice, but the part I'd really like to get working is the git branch info. I've been googling, but haven't found anything yet. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to zsh, so links to helpful resources would also be appreciated.

```
zsh --version
zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)
```

Comment: Did you reinstall git? Is git in your when the prompt is created path?
The git command is actually git-branch, not under-socre.

Comment: I wrote my own function to give me information about my git branch that I named "git_branch", e.g.:

git_branch() {

Answer (score 1):

You probably have `PROMPT_SUBST` turned off. To turn it on:

```
setopt promptsubst
```

You can add that to your `~/.zhsrc` file. You may need to remove or comment out a line similar to `unsetopt promptsubst` or `setopt nopromptsubst` (the option names are not case sensitive and underscores are optional and ignored).

See the "Prompting" section in `man zshoptions` and the "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES" section in `man zshmisc` for more information.